# How can I get my joystick name, in a shell/bash context?

Tags: scripts, joystick

When running from a terminal I type:

```
jstest /dev/input/js1 | grep '^Joystick'
```

and get the name.

But the `jstest` cmd is interactive, and needs a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to finish.

How can I get such result into a shell script?

---

`xinput -list` does not list my usb joysticks.
I could use `lsusb`: it returns names but not the js position.

Suppose I have 2 joysticks (but don't know in which positions they are) and want to calibrate them.
My goal is:

```
if (name("/dev/input/js0")=="Thrustmaster") then
    jscal -s <Thrustmaster params> /dev/input/js0
    jscal -s <FooJs params> /dev/input/js1
elif (name("/dev/input/js0")=="FooJs") then
    jscal -s <FooJs params> /dev/input/js0
    jscal -s <Thrustmaster params> /dev/input/js1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the program below the order in which the are listed is different dependent in which USB slot they are plugged. It is consistent with the order of jstest when I tried it.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.joystick.init()

joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()

for nr in range(0,joystick_count):
    joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(nr)
    print(joystick.get_name())
```

Answer (score 0):

`jstest /dev/input/js0 | grep Joy > out.txt & sleep 1; pkill jstest`

It puts the jstest, grep and the redirect of the ouput to a file in the background . Gives it one second to its thing and then kills it (Ctrl-c essentially).
You will find your information in out.txt.